# Adobe Business Catalyst - Custom Secure Zones

Tags: javascript, html, web, business-catalyst

I am wanting to create a template for a Secure Zone but depending on the login, depends on what logo appears in the header. Is this possible using Business Catalyst or do I need some other sort of coding for this like Javascript or something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is completely possible. You need to ensure Liquid is enabled as this requires Liquid to work. Here is the code I use to do this.

First we need to know what secure zone the person logging in is a part of and assign the info:

```
{module_data resource="customers" version="v3" template="" collection="customerInfo" fields="id,firstName,middleName,lastName,company,email1,email2,email3,username,mobilePhone,wholesaler,webAddress" where="\{'$or':\[    \{'email1.value': '{{this.globals.user.email}}'\},\{'email2.value': '{{this.globals.user.email}}'\},\{'email3.value': '{{this.globals.user.email}}'\}\]\}"}

{%assign userInfo = customerInfo.items[0]-%}
```

We then need to assign which secure zones the customer is a member of:

```
{module_data resource="customers" subresource="securezones" resourceId="{{userInfo.id}}" version="v3" template="" collection="customerZones"}

{% if customerZones.totalItemsCount > 0 -%}

    {% for item in customerZones.items -%}

        {% case item.zoneId -%}
          {% when '13435' -%}
            {% assign wholesaler = 'True' -%}
          {% when '51' -%}
            {% assign customer = 'True' -%}
          {% else -%}
            {% assign no-portal = 'True' -%}
        {% endcase -%}

    {% endfor -%}

{% endif -%}
```

In the above code you see the following lines:

```
{% when '13435' -%}
    {% assign wholesaler = 'True' -%}
```

The `13435` is the ID of the secure zone. Replace that number with your ID. Then you have:

```
{% assign wholesaler = 'True' -%}
```

`wholesaler` is a name I am assigning to someone who is a member of this secure zone. You can use any name you would like. You can add as many secure zones to the `case` as you need to.

What the above code does is tell the system which secure zones the person logging in is subscribed to. Once you have this info, you run simple logic checks:

```
{% if wholesaler == 'True' -%}
    <!-- CONTENT TO SHOW TO MEMBER OF THIS SECURE ZONE -->
{% elsif customer == 'True' -%}
    <!-- CONTENT TO SHOW TO MEMBER OF THIS SECURE ZONE -->
{% else -%}
    <!-- CONTENT TO SHOW TO EVERYONE ELSE -->
{% endif -%}
```

I should note that if a person is a member of multiple secure zones, then the content for each secure zone will be shown.

You can also take a look at [this documentation](http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/developers#!/how-tos/customers-module_data/secure-zones-related) from BC on performing this action for more info.
Hope this information can help guide you in the correct direction.